# Preview report using BIRT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, birt

I am using worklight 6.2 and would want to view reports from WLREPORT database from eclipse using BIRT. I already have the WLREPORT database generated and have populated the tables with data after running my application. I have also followed the steps in the ibm site and still did not succeed.

This is what I did:

1. Installed BIRT in eclipse. (I am using Eclipse Juno SR2)
2. Create a report project and have imported the report-template files to the project.
3. Add data source that connects to the database (MySQL). I tested the connection and was successful.
4. Click view reports in web view but nothing shows.

I have also updated my worklight.properties to point to the database. Am I still missing anything?

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to use BIRT reports instead the new analytics WAR file that came in 6.2? The installation and configuration is much more simplified than the BIRT reports. It uses a filestore instead of a SQL database. It also contains all of the charts that BIRT has and also has additional charts.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Will try to use analytics. thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry for the late reply. but, is it possible to export the reports in analytics?

Comment: Yes. Please read the documentation... http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_raw_reports.html

Answer (score 0):

The user ended up switching from BIRT reports to the built-in Operational Analytics feature, per the recommendation given in the comments section, making the question less relevant.